# Need to open the OS calendar at a specific date from a React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native, calendar, android-permissions

I am trying to open **OS default Calendar**. But Facing issue while trying to open android **calendar**.

**Please help me to fix this issue**

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('calshow:');
} else if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Linking.canOpenURL('content://com.android.calendar/time').then((val) => {
      Linking.openURL('content://com.android.calendar/time')
    }).catch(err => console.log('err ==>>', err))
}
```

Value always throw false, and unable to open android OS default Calendar

```
Linking.canOpenURL("content://com.android.calendar/time")
  .then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
    // Always show false
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err)); // // Need help to validate : content://com.android.calendar/time
```

help to validate : content://com.android.calendar/time

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: Value always throw false, and unable to open android OS default Calendar 

Linking.canOpenURL('content://com.android.calendar/time').then((val) => {
   console.log(val); // Always show false
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

// Need help to validate : content://com.android.calendar/time